# Printing an Image

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET WebForms app. On a page of the app I have an image (implemented by DevExpess control AspxBinaryImage).

I have to add Print Image functionality on the page: a button Print that prints out the image (not the whole page)

How can I implement this?

Comment: 35 questions and not a single accepted answer. Tsk tsk.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS to define which parts of your webpage should be printed:

```
@media print {
#somediv {display: none}
}
```

Then you can implement a javascript:window.print() callback in your button that will cause the browser to only print the elements you want to be printed (i.e. your image).